# Defining C# events without an external delegate definition

Tags: c#, events, delegates

just out of curiosity: is it possible to define events in C# without defining a delegate type beforhand?

something like `public event (delegate void(int)) EventName`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible; [ECMA-334](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf), § 17.7 states:

> The type of an event declaration shall be a delegate-type (§11.2)

and § 11.2 defines:

```
delegate-type:
    type-name
```

However, since C# 3, you can use various predefined generic types such as `Action<int>` so that you almost don’t have to define your own delegate types.

Answer (score 25):

There's built in generic delegate types, `Action<>` and `Func<>`, where Action returns void. Each generic type argument is type type of the argument to be passed to the delegate. e.g.

```
public event Action<int> EventName;
```

Also, there's a generic `EventHandler<T>` to follow the convention of passing the Object sender, and having an EventArgs type.

Answer (score 1):

No, AFAIK this is not possible with C#.

The reason why I think so is that a .NET event is basically a delegate with certain restrictions added. That is, the `event` keyword does not define a new *type*; conceptually speaking, it's more like a *modifier* (think things such as `private` or `readonly`), which is used in a declaration to modify an already existing delegate type. It's this modification that adds the restrictions:

```
public EventHandler x;
```

This is a normal delegate that can be passed around (copied) and invoked by anyone.

```
public event EventHandler x;
```

Under the hood, this is also a normal delegate, but it can only be set (`=`) and invoked by the type containing `x`; further, the delegate cannot be passed to third parties; these can only perform the `add` (`+=`) and `remove` (`-=`) operations.